# checking if user input is equal to a randomly generated list of integers

Tags: c#, oop, random, console, int

I have a problem that I cannot seem to figure out.
I want to make a program that generates two random integers that are between 1 and 10 and then asks the user for input. The user must enter the same integers that were given by the program.
I know it probably sounds very simple, but I cant get my head around it. Help would be absolutely great.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Prototyping3
 {
     class Program
     {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

             Random random = new Random();
            List<int> selection = new List<int>();

            selection.Add(random.Next(0, 9));
            selection.Add(random.Next(0, 9));
            foreach (int s in selection) 
            {
                 Console.Write(s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("...");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            int converted = Convert.ToInt32(input);

            for (int i = 0; i < selection.Count(); i++) 
            {
                 if (converted == selection[i])
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("correct");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("wrong");
                 }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is my existing code. The program gives two integers, but when I enter them it just tells me that I'm wrong. When I enter one of the numbers it says im correct and wrong. I dont know what the problem is. Again, help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like if you entered the right first number, it would tell you correct. But since you never re-enter a second number and store it in `converted`, the second number will be wrong (unless the two numbers are the same. You should ask for user input again, or just take both numbers in at once.

Answer (score 0):

It's looping so when you input a number it loops on the next `selection` collection which has `2`. Assuming order of doesn't matter. If it does then just do a for loop and check both collection's index if they are equal.

```
List<int> userInput = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < selection.Count(); i++)
{
 var int32 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 userInput.Add(int32);
}

Console.WriteLine(userInput.Intersect(selection).Count() == selection.Count ? "correct" : "wrong");
```

Comment: What is your objective? How many user input do you need? Do you just want one input number of keep asking based on the number of items in the collection?

Comment: I just need the program to check if the two numbers that the user entered are the same as the ones it gave. Then write "correct". Nothing seems to work.

Comment: "Numbers" But you are only doing one `Console.Read` so I assumed that you only want to check one user input and see if its in the collection.

Comment: Thats what I want to do.

Comment: That crashed it for some reason

Comment: Thank you very much for attempting to help btw

Comment: I can't just spoon feed you. It didn't crash I'm pretty sure. You probably just copy and pasted the entire code. You want a `Console.Read` at the end of the code, right? If it did crash, what is the crash?